# MassTransit3+Azure Service Bus queue naming conventions

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, masstransit, azure-servicebus-queues

I've encountered a weird issue with naming of queues, which are created in Azure Service Bus and used by MassTransit.

Uri is `"sb://{@namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{path}/{queueName}"`

E.g. if a path equals to `dev` and queueName contains `dev` as a substring, e.g. `devices` than `dev` is removed and I see a queue with a name `ices` created.
Same happens if path = `test` as well.

**I've have not found any reserved words for queue naming so I wonder if there are any.**

That issue happens only while sending messages in ASP.NET Web Api process. For Azure Worker Role everything works fine.

Used methods are:

```
public static Uri BuildQueueUri(string @namespace, string path, string queueName)
    {
        return new Uri($"sb://{@namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{path}/{queueName}");
    }

protected Task<ISendEndpoint> EstablishSendEndpoint(string queueName)
    {
        Uri uri = BusConfiguration.BuildQueueUri(
            Settings.GetSetting(ConfigKeys.ServiceBusNamespace),
            Settings.GetSetting(ConfigKeys.ServiceBusPath),
            queueName);

        return BusControl.GetSendEndpoint(uri);
    }


public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SendGetIpsToInterceptCommand()
    {
        ISendEndpoint endpoint = await EstablishSendEndpoint(BusConfiguration.SendCommandsQueue);
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();

        await endpoint.Send<ICGetItemsToInterceptCommand>(new
        {
            CommandId = guid

        });

        return Ok(guid);
    }
```

MassTransit configuration (using Autofac)

```
private static void RegisterMicroserviceBus(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(c =>
                Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(sbc =>
                {
                    var serviceUri = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb",
                        Settings.GetSetting(ConfigKeys.ServiceBusNamespace), 
                        Settings.GetSetting(ConfigKeys.ServiceBusPath));

                    sbc.Host(serviceUri, h =>
                    {
                        h.TokenProvider =
                            TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(
                                Settings.GetSetting(ConfigKeys.ServiceBusKeyName),
                                Settings.GetSetting(ConfigKeys.ServiceBusAccessKey), 
                                TimeSpan.FromDays(365),
                                TokenScope.Namespace);
                    });
                }))
            .SingleInstance()
            .As<IBusControl>()
            .As<IBus>();
    }
```

Comment: `dev` is a reserved word in many OSes, I am wondering if this has any effect.

Comment: This is probably a bug, in how the queue names are parsed. I'll look more closely and try to reproduce.